# How can I loop over a List that is bigger then the loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class DoorClass
    {
        public HoriDoorManager Door;
        public bool doorState;
        public Transform[] DoorShieldFXLocked;
    }

    public bool allDoors = false;
    public DoorClass[] doorclass;

    private List<HoriDoorManager> Doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();
    private Renderer rend;
    private Shader unlitcolor;
    private List<GameObject> DoorShieldFXLocked = new List<GameObject>();

    private void Start()
    {
        DoorShieldFXLocked = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("DoorShield").ToList();
        unlitcolor = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");

        var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
        doorclass = new DoorClass[doors.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++)
        {
            Doors.Add(doors[i].GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>());
            LockDoorState(i, allDoors);
            doorclass[i] = new DoorClass();
            doorclass[i].Door = Doors[i];
            doorclass[i].doorState = allDoors;
        }
    }
```

How can I loop over the doorClass and also over the DoorShieldFXLocked.
Each doorClass have two DoorShieldFXLocked items.

For example:

```
doorClass1
    DoorShieldFXLocked
    DoorShieldFXLocked

doorClass2
    DoorShieldFXLocked
    DoorShieldFXLocked
```

In the Start I need to assign to each doorClass two DoorShieldFXLocked to the DoorShieldFXLocked Transform array.

The size of doorClass is 13 (index 0 to 12) and the DoorShieldFXLocked list size is 24 (index 0 to 23).

Comment: 24 isn't double 13, how will you fot 2 door shields per door? If you always know it's 2 door shields per door you can keep the loop as it is and do doorclass[i].DoorShieldFxLocked[0] = DoorShieldFxLocked[i × 2]; doorclass[i].DoorShieldFxLocked[1] = DoorShieldFxLocked[i × 2 + 1];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume the following, you don't need to loop over the `DoorShieldFXLocked` array; simple math works:

At `doorClass[0]`, you need to use `DoorShieldFXLocked[0]` and `DoorShieldFXLocked[1]`.

At `doorClass[1]`, you need to use `DoorShieldFXLocked[2]` and `DoorShieldFXLocked[3]`.
etc.

In this case, you can see that each pair of `DoorShieldFXLocked` indices is `2*i` and `(2*i)+1`.

If, however, you need to find two specific doors, you'd use a nested loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++)
{
    ...
    for (int j=0; j< DoorShieldFXLocked.Length; ++j)
    {
       //test and Add if needed
    }
}
```